# haskell import problem

Tags: haskell, import

I have a module "Dictionary", declared in a file "Dictionary.hs".

in the same directory i have a file "Def.hs" which imports Dictionary

here's the error i get

... /edsl/Def.hs:4:7:
    Could not find module `Dictionary':
      locations searched:
        Dictionary.hs
        Dictionary.lhs

... /edsl/Dictionary.hs is there. it's permissions are such that it can be written to or read from by anyone.

i really have no idea why i can't import. i'm using ghc 6.12.1 on mac os x 10.5.8

*edit*
here's the relevant code

in Dictionary.hs

```
module Dictionary where
...
```

and in in Def.hs

```
module Def where
import Control.Exception
import Data.Dynamic
import Dictionary
...
```

am i just defining the module incorrectly? i want to export all symbols.

Comment: Seeing some code would be helpful.

Comment: can you provide the line where you import Def? is that `:l edsl/Def.hs` in ghci?

Comment: i just load Def into ghci with: 

ghci edsl/Def.hs.

i was under the belief that loading a file in ghci searched for and built all dependancies before building the file to load.

Answer (score 2):

i just found the problem. i'm using komodo edit, and the command the i created to load a file into ghci doesn't change the working directory.

doh.